# How to make JScrollPane Transparent in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I have to display a long Text on my screen so I wrapped`JTextArea` inside `JScrollPane`.Now I want to make this combo-container to be transparent such that only text is seen which looks like a `JLabel` is written on `JFrame`.

So I made them transparent using the following code

```
class Body extends JTextArea
{
    Body(String text)
    {
        super(text);
        setOpaque(false);
        setSize(400,200);
        setWrapStyleWord(true);
        setLineWrap(true);
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(new Color(12,25,55,0));
        g.fillRect(0,0,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight());
    }
}

class CustomScrollPane extends JScrollPane
{
    CustomScrollPane(JTextArea textArea)
    {
        super(textArea);
        setOpaque(false);
        setSize(400,200);
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(new Color(220,10,10,0));
        g.fillRect(0,0,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight());
    }
}
```

But I am getting opaque container.

When I directly added the `JTextArea` to `JFrame` it is transparent ,but adding it through `JScrollPane` creates problem.

Any Help?

Comment: set the scrollPane's viewport !opaque

Comment: @kleopatra : How can I do it?Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you can set the `JScrollPane` view port's opaque to `false` by asking the `JScrollPane` instance to return it's view port:

   ```
    jScrollPane1.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
   ```
2. In your code why you are setting size using `setSize(Dimension)` method. Don't tell me you working with `NullLayout`. Learn to use [Layout Mangers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html). They will make you happy.

**Edit:**

Ok, use an extension of `JViewPort`, you can paint anything inside if necessary:

```
class MyViewPort extends JViewport
{

    public MyViewPort() {
        setOpaque(false);
    }

}
```

Then set an instance of `MyViewPort` as your `JScrollPane`'s view port invoking:

```
setViewport(new MyViewPort())
```

Comment: :I tried `getViewPort().setOpaque(false);` inside `CutomeScrollPane` constructor but it is still opaque.

Comment: @InsaneCoder, edited the answer. I have seen you are painting inside the `paintComponent` function. Do you want your component to be semi transparent ? then try setting the alpha(`0-255`) value of the color you created inside this function. For semi transparent it is `127`